# How to create class library package in dotnet core on non windows machines?

Tags: .net

I'm running dotnet core on ubuntu 14.04. I'm new to both linux and dotnet core.
VScode can't create a project, it creates only an empty file (Since it is an editor and not an IDE like VS). 'Dotnet new' creates a simple console app template. Yeoman is outdated (They are doing their best but looking at that there is major shift in how ASP.NET Core works, it'll take them  few months to create templates)
I want to create class library and include it in my project. I googled and found no documentation as how to create it.

Environment Data:

dotnet version output :

```
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-beta-001675)

Product Information:
 Version:     1.0.0-beta-001675
 Commit Sha:  N/A

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  14.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 Runtime Id:  ubuntu.14.04-x64
```

VScode version 0.10.8 and 0.10.10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use dotnet new at the command line see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-new

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this older question from a current perspective (`dotnet --version: 2.0.0` on Ubuntu)

- create a directory for the library project and make it the current directory

  ```
  mkdir dotnetlibrary
  cd dotnetlibrary
  ```
- create a library project

  ```
  dotnet new classlib
  dotnet restore    # seems to be not needed anymore but doesn't hurt
  ```
- create/test the classes (in VS Code, or...)
- build the project

  ```
  dotnet build
  ```
- create an exportable .dll (if needed)

  ```
  dotnet publish --configuration Release  --self-contained
  ```
- create a Nuget Package

  ```
  dotnet pack --configuration Release
  ```

References

- [Using .NET Core in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/dotnet)
- [.NET Core Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/)